# Using Javascript Image object to handle images

Tags: javascript, image

I need to preview an image using javascript before upload to provide a crop facility. For this purpose, I create an Image object in javascript.

```
var image = new Image();
```

To confine big images to a limited space, I access the height and width of the image using `image.width` and `image.height`

For some of the images, I find that this value is shown as zero and for which when I inspected the `image` object, found that `image.mimeType` has the value `Unspecified Error` (Even the file creationdate shows unspecified error).

As such I am not able to preview those images. How do I solve the problem?

Answer (score 4):

You won't be able to get a preview of image from the client system. You have to ***upload the image to a server and can show the image preview from there***.

Reading files from the client system is a security threat and most browsers won't allow that. In earlier versions of IE you can get that, but won't be available in newer versions and other browsers.

Comment: "You won't be able to get a preview of image from the client system" ?? I am able to do this for some of the images where the mimetype is not unspecified error?? How will you justify

Comment: @Ajay I can't explain why you are able to read some images from the client system. Normally that is not supposed to happen.. imagine: opening a webpage that reads your hard disks and steals private data!

Comment: inorder to upload the file, your webpage has to read the local image file rite? that is what is happening here as well??