# Photo crop after upload functionality

Tags: asp.net, file-upload

Once I upload an image to the server (asp.net), I need to **display** this uploaded image for cropping. What is the best-practice to achieve the same(ie how do I send te image back to the client for display)? . I have tried giving a preview option before upload. But this does not seem to be working for all images. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1997954/using-javascript-image-object-to-handle-images)

**Addition :**
[I know JCrop is available , but the point of the question is how to send the image back ofr display]

Answer (score 2):

You can first upload the image to your server and show a preview from there. After successful upload you can use javascript to select the region for crop.

Here is a nice [**crop plugin**](http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop.html) in jQuery.

Then you can get the dimensions of the crop region and use C# or any other server side language to make a new image with these dimensions.

See

[**Image Editing: Saving, Cropping, and Resizing**](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-image-editing-saving-cropping-and-resizing)

Comment: once the image is uploaded, how do I show the preview.. That is my question.

Comment: You can set the source of an img tag to the location of image in server.